# QTP/UFT - Access multiple datasheets in loop

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am comparatively new to QTP/UFT. I am writing a test and need to use data from Global as well as Local Data Sheet in same test.

My `for` loop is something like:

```
Datatable.GetSheet("Global")
RowCount = Datatable.GetRowCount
For Cntr = 1 to RowCount
    Datatable.SetCurrentRow(Cntr)
    msgbox Datatable("Form", dtGlobalSheet) 'Form is my column Name from Global Data Sheet'

    Datatable.GetSheet("Action1")
    RowCount2 = Datatable.GetRowCount
    For Cntr2 = 1 to RowCount2
        Datatable.SetCurrentRow(Cntr2)
        msgbox Datatable("Number", dtGlobalSheet) 'Number is my column Name from Action1 Data Sheet'
    Next
Next
```

My column values are getting messed up from both sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your datatables to variables, in order to better work with it.

- You are calling `Datatable.GetSheet("Global")` but not assigning it to anywhere.
- When you use `Datatable.GetRowCount` you are not actually telling UFT from which datatable to get the rowcount and that is probably one of your problems.
- In the end of your code you are using `msgbox Datatable("Number", dtGlobalSheet)` but you should probably be using `msgbox Datatable("Number", dtLocalSheet)` (assuming you assigned those variables somewhere in your code).

Check this possible solution (not tested):

```
Dim dtGlobal : Set dtGlobal = Datatable.GetSheet("Global")
Dim dtLocal : Set dtLocal = Datatable.GetSheet("Action1")
RowCount = dtGlobal.GetRowCount
For Cntr = 1 to RowCount
    'Working with global datatable
    dtGlobal.SetCurrentRow(Cntr)
    msgbox dtGlobal.GetParameter("Form") 'Form is my column Name from Global Data Sheet'

    'Working with local datatable
    RowCount2 = dtLocal.GetRowCount
    For Cntr2 = 1 to RowCount2
        dtLocal.SetCurrentRow(Cntr2)
        msgbox dtLocal.GetParameter("Number") 'Number is my column Name from Action1 Data Sheet'
    Next
Next
```

PS.: After defining exactly what data is coming from which datatable, you may want to check your loop to make sure your logic is correct, as I did not check that part. Let me know if this works for you.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks Victor for the quick reply.. This works with only one change.. I am using UFT 12.54 and it doesn't support dtGlobal.Value("Form"). So I just replaced it with dtGlobal.GetParameter("Form")

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. Unfortunately I don't have UFT anymore so I checked the method from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_data_table_methods.htm) since I didn't remember it and was not able to test it beforehand. I'd advise you to bookmark this website for future references ;)

Comment: Sure, I did. Thanks!